# TabControl in WinPhone 8

Tags: windows-phone, tabcontrol

I need to port existing iOS app to WP8 platform. In the iOS app there is a TabControl.
Can I use such design in WP app and does Microsoft accept it or I should adapt UI to WP
design guidelines and use Pivot or Panorama controls?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to port your application according to Metro design guidelines; then you can go for Pivot Control.

1- [App tabs (Pivot control) for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/design/hh202890%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

2- [Design library for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/fa00461b-abe1-41d1-be87-0b0fe3d3389d%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Otherwise you have to build your own custom control, as per your requirement.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Will the app with TabControl like iOS pass sertification? And can I than use it in WinRT version?

Comment: In both case, Yes.. it will passing certification.